# Deserialization of [simple type, class pl.play.Experiment] by passing existing instance (of pl.play.Experiment) not supported

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

In my program I would like to create an object (using JSON input) and, at some point, update it (again: using another JSON input with the same schema, different values).

Classes:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class Experiment {
    Integer id;
    String type;
    Monster monster;
}

@Data
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class Monster {
    String name;
    String type;
}
```

JsonInputs:

```
monster_json1:
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "whateverzaur",
    "monster": {
        "name": "Andrzej",
        "type": "cokolwiek"
    }
}

--
monster_json2:
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "whateverzaur",
    "monster": {
        "name": "Andrzej",
        "type": "diff"
    }
}
```

I create object using objectMapper:
`Experiment experiment = objectMapper.readValue(monster_json1,Experiment.class);`

I've tried updating it like this:
`experiment = objectMapper.readerForUpdating(experiment).readValue(monster_json2);`

I get error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Deserialization of [simple type, class pl.play.Experiment] by passing existing instance (of pl.play.Experiment) not supported

I know that I (in this case) make changes by calling setter for property type:
`experiment.getMonster().setType("xxxx");`

When my classes get more params, gain more complexity and I will need to update more then one param at the time, I will need different way to do it. Because new data go to me via JSON response using readerForUpdate seems reasonable.

Comment: Need more time to find the root cause, but removing @Jacksonized in `Experiment` should work

Comment: Following suggestion from @samabcde I've removed @Jacksonized annotation. Error changed to more common "Cannot construct instance of `Experiment`". Then adding constructors / Lombok annotations was needed. Adding @AllArgsConstructor and @RequiredArgsConstructor solves that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Cause

Deserialization using Builder does not work with `readerForUpdating`, as suggested [by Jan Rieke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10026074/jan-rieke),

> updating an existing instance can never be achieved using a builder: builders always create new instances

#### Details

When using `@Jacksonized`,

> Configure Jackson to use the builder for deserialization using @JsonDeserialize(builder=Foobar.FoobarBuilder[Impl].class) on the class (where Foobar is the name of the annotated class).

we tell Jackson to deserialize using the builder.

With the error message and referring to [jackson 2.15 BuilderBasedDeserializer](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.15/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/BuilderBasedDeserializer.java#L252),

```java
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt,
            Object value) throws IOException
    {
        // 26-Oct-2016, tatu: I cannot see any of making this actually
        //    work correctly, so let's indicate problem right away
        JavaType valueType = _targetType;
        // Did they try to give us builder?
        Class<?> builderRawType = handledType();
        Class<?> instRawType = value.getClass();
        if (builderRawType.isAssignableFrom(instRawType)) {
            return ctxt.reportBadDefinition(valueType, String.format(
                    "Deserialization of %s by passing existing Builder (%s) instance not supported",
                    valueType, builderRawType.getName()));
        }
        return ctxt.reportBadDefinition(valueType, String.format(
                "Deserialization of %s by passing existing instance (of %s) not supported",
                valueType, instRawType.getName()));
    }
```

We can see this feature is not ready for use from the comment.

#### Workaround

1. Do not use @Jacksonized
2. Use other library like [Spring BeanUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html) to update the values.

Comment: I would not consider it a bug, because updating an existing instance can never be achieved using a builder: builders always create new instances.

Comment: @JanRieke, you are right, let me update the post. But it is quite difficult to figure out the problem behind.